# Discord.py Warning Command (help me) mass dm

Tags: python, python-3.x, command, discord.py

A few days ago I was trying to create a warning command, a dm mass type, but instead of sending to all server users, send just a few people to a specific role.

I was able to create just one mass dm command

```py
        @commands.command()
    async def all(self, ctx,*,message):
        for mem in ctx.guild.members:
            try:
                await mem.send(message)
                await ctx.send(f'**Sent dm to:** {mem.name}')
            except:
                await ctx.send(f'**User dm closed** {mem.name}')
                print('User dm closed')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the docs of Discord.py rewrite you can really find everything. Including the objects a member object has: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#member. When you read the documentation you will see that you can use `mem.roles` to get a list of role objects the member has.

You can iterate through the list of roles the user has and check if the role's string value equals the desired role. If it is the desired role you can message the member.

The reason that you need to do `str(role) == desired_role` instead of `role == desired_role` is that `role` is an object. And you cant compare an object with a string.

```
@commands.command()
async def message_user_w_role(self, ctx, desired_role):
    # For every member in the guild in which the message was send.
    for mem in ctx.guild.members:
        # Members.roles gives list with roles. Thus you need to iterate and check if role == desired role
        for role in mem.roles:
            if str(role) == desired_role:
                try:
                    # Sends the dm if the user has the desired role
                    await mem.send("YOUR MESSAGE")
                    await ctx.send("ANOTHER MESSAGE")
                    break
                except:
                    # If the user closed his dm's
                    await ctx.send("ANOTHER MESSAGE")
                    print("User dm closed")
```